# How do I rewrite this trigger to use a cursor or set based approach?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, cursor

The below trigger is supposed to delete rows from a `ProductOrders` table when a Product OrderNo is updated for a prodct.  This works fine from the front-end, but if someone does a mass update on the back-end (updates multiple order no's), I need a way to run this trigger for all product orderNo updates.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trgAfterOrderNoUpdate] ON [Products]
    FOR UPDATE
AS 

DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier

SELECT @id = i.ID
FROM inserted i

if UPDATE(OrderNo)
DELETE FROM ProductOrders
WHERE ID= @id
```

Comment: never ever consider using a cursor in a trigger.

Comment: @HLGEM - Why is using a cursor in a trigger a bad thing?  I am new to triggers, so please forgive the dumb question, although there are no such thing :)

Comment: Because cursors are slow and you can lock up all the other users while you process a million record update that should take seconds aand now takes 18 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE PO
FROM ProductOrders PO
INNER JOIN INSERTED I
    ON PO.ID = I.ID
INNER JOIN DELETED D
    ON PO.ID = D.ID
WHERE I.OrderNo <> D.OrderNo
OR (I.OrderNo IS NULL AND D.OrderNo IS NOT NULL)
OR (I.OrderNo IS NOT NULL AND D.OrderNo IS NULL)
```

Comment: I tried this, but the trigger didn't delete anything.

Comment: OK, I got this to work. I had some ids mixed up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When using triggers keep in mind that the inserted or deleted items are tables and not a single row. You will need to join on the inserted table to delete the correct rows

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trgAfterOrderNoUpdate] ON [Products]
    FOR UPDATE
AS 


DELETE FROM ProductOrders
WHERE ID in (select ID 
             from    inserted i
                  inner join Products p on i.Id = p.ID
             where i.OrderNo != p.OrderNo)
```

Comment: I was getting the id from inserted in my post, correct?

Comment: yes, you were getting the id from inserted, the problem is that there is more than one Id to get.

Comment: Ah I understand, so basically the difference between mine and yours is that mine would just do 1 row and yours is going to delete based on a group of ids?

Comment: Is there a big difference between yours and @Lamak's.  Seems like the main difference is you are using a subquery and he is using a join.

Comment: Yes, @xaisoft, that is exactly the difference, which is why it worked in code (only one product) but not when someone tried to delete more than one.

Comment: Lamak's code deletes the ProductOrders only if the Product.OrderNo actually changed. Gary's deletes them whenever the OrderNo column is updated, whether or not the actual value changed...which is all that your question required as well.

Comment: @Gary - I guess mdisibio pointed it out.  I updated 2 records, once that actually had the OrderNo changed, but it deleted all records when it should have only deleted the ones where the orderNo actually changed.

Comment: @mdisibio - The part that confuses me with your statement though is that Gary has a `if Update(OrderNo)` section.

Comment: I copied that from the original question.

Comment: @Gary - How do I modify your query to only delete from ProductOrders where Product.OrderNo actually changes?

Comment: `IF UPDATE(OrderNo)` will only run if the column OrderNo was part of the UPDATE statement, so it is efficient to keep it in the trigger. However, the statement `UPDATE Products SET OrderNo = OrderNo` will not change a single OrderNo, but the conditional will return true because the OrderNo column is included in the updated statement. In other words `IF UPDATE(col)` is not a check on whether or not a value changed. It is a check on whether or not the column is included in the UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you really want to use foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`

[Technet: Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[Technet: Triggers Compared to Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189261%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

If you really have to use a trigger, you'll need something like this:

```
DELETE po
FROM ProductOrders po
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, OrderNo FROM deleted
  EXCEPT
  SELECT id, OrderNo FROM inserted
) i ON i.id = po.id
```